# Very simple code - Unity 3d - IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class Button : MonoBehaviour {
    public Material[] mButton;
    Renderer rend;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(mButton[0]);
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.sharedMaterial = mButton[0];
    }
```

I am getting a "Index Out of Bounds" error at the rend.sharedMaterial=mButton[0] line. It is an array of two elements. I have different materials in each of the two locations of the array. The Debug.Log accurately shows which material is in the [0] location.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you log the sharedMaterial? `Debug.Log(rend.sharedMaterial)`

Comment: Can you please double-check that the error happens at the rend.sharedMaterial line, and not the Debug.Log line? (E.g. it sometimes happens that one assigns the same script to two different gameObjects accidentally -- one would now have an empty material list, thus throw an error at the Debug.Log line.)

Comment: @SérgioCastelani  Sorry for the delay, I was experimenting with another method of doing this. I get the following error: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"   if I put 'rend.sharedMaterial' in the debug.log

Comment: @PhilippLenssen  That solved it! Thank you! Can you put it in an answer so that I can select it?

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted by @PhilippLenssen solved the issue.

His comment:
"Can you please double-check that the error happens at the rend.sharedMaterial line, and not the Debug.Log line? (E.g. it sometimes happens that one assigns the same script to two different gameObjects accidentally -- one would now have an empty material list, thus throw an error at the Debug.Log line.) "

Once I commented out the `Debug.Log(mButton[0]);` line, the error cleared.